# C# WPF CanExecute for InvokeCommandAction

Tags: wpf, triggers, interaction, canexecute

Is it possible to set a CanExecute on an InteractionTrigger?

This is my code, but I know in some instances the ButtonCommand will be NULL, So I want to be sure that I do not cause any issues.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <i:KeyTrigger Key="Return">
    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{TemplateBinding ButtonCommand}" />
  </i:KeyTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Many thanks

Comment: Maybe you could use the `IsEnabled` property of `InvokeCommandAction` for that?

Comment: If the command is null, does anything bad actually happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If and when `ButtonCommand` is `null`, the `Command` property of the `InvokeCommandAction` will also be set to `null` and since the implementation checks the reference before trying to invoke the command you won't get any `NullReferenceException`.

So you don't have to do anything at all. This should work as expected out of the box.